# Why can I add a gradle task dependency on something like assembleDebug but not lint?

Tags: android, gradle

Say I'm creating a new build task for my Android project, called `myTask`.

```
myTask << {
   println 'This is my task!'
}
```

Let's first say this depends on the android `assembleDebug` task. Doing the following works perfectly:

```
myTask.dependsOn assembleDebug

> gradle myTask -m

(omitted for brevity)
:app:zipalignDebug SKIPPED
:app:assembleDebug SKIPPED
:app:myTask SKIPPED
```

Now let's say that my build is dependent on the `lint` task. Great, the following should work, right? Nope.

```
myTask.dependsOn lint

> gradle myTask -m

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find property 'lint' on project ':app'.
```

You have to do the following:

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    myTask.dependsOn lint
}
```

Ok, so now let's say we have build flavors, and I need to depend on `assembleFlavor1Debug`. Should work like `assembleDebug`, right? Nope. Works like `lint`. Needs evaluation.

My question is... why exactly are `lint` and `assembleFlavor1Debug` "evaluated" tasks and `assembleDebug` not?

Comment: Well, I don't know if this is the reason, but `lint` and product flavors are an Android plugin thing, while build types (and specifically `debug`) are part of core Gradle AFAIK.

Comment: The problem is, that lint and assembleFlavor1Debug are tasks that are created after the buildscript is evaluated. so when you declare `myTask.dependsOn lint` lint simply just does not exist yet. this is some sort of "flaw" in the way the gradle build model is created. The gradle team is currently working on a new way of modelling the build model which will solve this in the future. cheers,